# FullCalendar 4: businessHours through AJAX not showing in timeGridWeek

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am rendering a Calendar which is updated with businessHours and Events every time I choose a different resource.

The issue I am facing is with businessHours. I get the JSON right because it works fine in resourceTimeGridDay but when I switch to timeGridWeek businessHours aren't shown.

I get resources via AJAX and the JSON I get back is structured like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"2-1",
      "title":"Silvano",
      "businessHours":[
         {
            "startTime":"08:00",
            "endTime":"12:30",
            "daysOfWeek":"[1]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"14:00",
            "endTime":"17:30",
            "daysOfWeek":"[1]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"08:00",
            "endTime":"15:00",
            "daysOfWeek":"[2]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"08:00",
            "endTime":"12:30",
            "daysOfWeek":"[3]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"14:00",
            "endTime":"17:30",
            "daysOfWeek":"[3]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"08:00",
            "endTime":"15:00",
            "daysOfWeek":"[4]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"08:00",
            "endTime":"12:30",
            "daysOfWeek":"[5]"
         },
         {
            "startTime":"14:00",
            "endTime":"17:30",
            "daysOfWeek":"[5]"
         }
      ],
      "eventColor":"#bdbdbd",
      "servizi":[
         "2"
      ]
   }
]
```

Copying/Pasting these values in the calendar rendering code, businessHours are shown:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    businessHours: [{"startTime":"08:00","endTime":"12:30","daysOfWeek":"[1]"},{"startTime":"14:00","endTime":"17:30","daysOfWeek":"[1]"},{"startTime":"08:00","endTime":"15:00","daysOfWeek":"[2]"},{"startTime":"08:00","endTime":"12:30","daysOfWeek":"[3]"},{"startTime":"14:00","endTime":"17:30","daysOfWeek":"[3]"},{"startTime":"08:00","endTime":"15:00","daysOfWeek":"[4]"},{"startTime":"08:00","endTime":"12:30","daysOfWeek":"[5]"},{"startTime":"14:00","endTime":"17:30","daysOfWeek":"[5]"}]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

However I need them dynamically fetched (can be different week by week). I have looked at documentation but could not find any answer on this. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: AJAX isn't the problem. The issue is you're specifying business hours **per resource**. And timeGridWeek isn't a resource-aware view, so naturally since it cannot show resources, it also cannot show the business hours associated with any particular resource. The second piece of code you've shown is not equivalent to the first one.

Comment: "I need them dynamically fetched (can be different week by week)"...has nothing to do (directly) with associating them with a specific resource, and also has nothing to do with why they don't show up in your timeGrid view.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding a custom view in Calendar based on resourceTimeGrid:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        
                        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceDayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'resourceTimeGrid' ],
                        timeZone: 'UTC',
                        height: 'parent',
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'dayGridMonth,customResourceTimeGridWeek,resourceTimeGridDay,listWeek'
                        },
                        views: {
                            customResourceTimeGridWeek: {
                              type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
                              duration: { days: 7 },
                              buttonText: 'Week'
                            }
                        },...
```